# How to apply a function to each element of a rx-java Flowable?

Tags: java, rx-java

How to apply a function to each element in a flowable? I am trying to apply a function to each item in a flowable publisher and collect the result but the function never gets called.

```
CompletionStage<Void> batchUpdate(Page<AClass> page); //Given

Completion<Void> updateItems(){
    final var futures = new ArrayList<CompletionStage<Void>>();
    final Flowable<Page<AClass>> flowable = getFlowablePublisher();
    flowable.map(this::batchUpdate).map(futures::add); //batchUpdate never gets called
    return CompletableFuture.allOf(futures.toArray(CompletableFuture[]::new));
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to do something like `return flowable.flatMap( x -> Flowable.fromCompletionStage(this.batchUpdate(x))).lastStage(null)`? You don't need the array list.